# index out of bound exception in hibernate3

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception

In my project i store and retrieve the timesheet in week manner.
i have a table like this

```
Id projectId activityId     Date       Spenttime
1     1       1          2014-11-10     8  
2     1       1          2014-11-11     8  
3     1       1          2014-11-12     8  
4     1       1          2014-11-13     8  
5     1       1          2014-11-14     8  
6     1       1          2014-11-15     8  
7     1       1          2014-11-16     8  
8     1       2          2014-11-10     8  
9     1       2          2014-11-11     8  
10    1       2          2014-11-12     8  
11    1       2          2014-11-13     8  
12    1       2          2014-11-14     8  
13    1       2          2014-11-15     8  
14    1       2          2014-11-16     8
15    2       1          2014-11-15     8
16    2       1          2014-11-16     8
```

i want the result for the above table,like below

```
projectId activityId 2014-11-10  2014-11-11 2014-11-12 2014-11-13 2014-11-14 2014-11-15 2014-11-16 
 1           1          8             8         8          8         8          8          8
 1           2          8             8         8          8         8          8          8
 2           1          0             0         0          0         0          8          8
```

My hibernate code for the above table

```
List<Timesheet> timesheetList=sessionfactory.getCurrentSession.createCriteria(Timesheet.class)
                              .add(Restrctions.between("date",formatter.parse("2014-11-09"),formatter.parse("2014-11-16"))
                              .list();
```

Retrieve logic:

```
List<DisplayTable> dispaly=new ArrayList<DisplayTable>();
for(int i=0;i<timesheetList.size();i+=7)
{
DisplayTable disp=new DisplayTable();
disp.setProjectId(timesheetList.get(i).getProjectId());
disp.setActivityId(timesheetList.get(i).getActivityId());
disp.setSpentTimeDate1(timesheetList.get(i).getSpentTime());
disp.setSpentTimeDate2(timesheetList.get(i+1).getSpentTime());
disp.setSpentTimeDate3(timesheetList.get(i+2).getSpentTime());
disp.setSpentTimeDate4(timesheetList.get(i+3).getSpentTime());
disp.setSpentTimeDate5(timesheetList.get(i+4).getSpentTime());
disp.setSpentTimeDate6(timesheetList.get(i+5).getSpentTime());
disp.setSpentTimeDate7(timesheetList.get(i+6).getSpentTime());
}
```

The above logic works fine in first two iteration.after that it throws index outofbound exception.
i know the exception is throwed because project 2 contains only 2 rows.

Is their any ways to achive the desired result in hibernate3?
Any help wll be greatly appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 1):

change the condition to

```
 i < timesheetList.size() - 6
```

because you don't want go +7 than  size

Comment: @jigar,I  tried the above code. but it misses the last one row of my result table.but i need to retrieve that also.

Comment: then `< size - 6` :) - just check the last case scenario, for example if your list is `size =8 `sized and for 0 = > 0- 6, 1 = > 1=7, you can not go to 3 now, so 2 and that is `size - 6`

Comment: also check the scenario where the list size is  `< 6` and determine how would you address it

Comment: @jigar,your logic fails in this scenario.I have a list size 16 as per my question.iteration one 0<10 print first row.iteration two 7<10 print second row.iteration three 14<10 fails.so third row is failed to print